# Can't figure out how Rails route helper should look

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am working on an assignment which includes adding a feature to Typo.

`rake routes` shows:

```
admin_content    /admin/content                     {:controller=>"admin/content", :action=>"index"}
                 /admin/content(/:action(/:id))     {:action=>nil, :id=>nil, :controller=>"admin/content"}
```

I need to create a route helper which matches the following RESTful route: `/admin/content/edit/:id` and an example of url is `/admin/content/edit/1`

But I can't figure out how to do it. I tried something like `admin_content_path(edit,some_article)` but it didn't work. (some_article is just an article object)

In `routes.rb` file:

```
# some other code

# Admin/XController
%w{advanced cache categories comments content profiles feedback general pages
 resources sidebar textfilters themes trackbacks users settings tags redirects seo post_types }.each do |i|
match "/admin/#{i}", :to => "admin/#{i}#index", :format => false
match "/admin/#{i}(/:action(/:id))", :to => "admin/#{i}", :action => nil, :id => nil, :format => false
end

#some other code
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you try `admin_content_path(:action => edit, :id => some_article)`?

Comment: Please add contents of `route.rb` file

Comment: `edit_admin_content_path(article)` did you try this?

Comment: I've added code from `routes.rb` file to my question.

Comment: The suggested ways didn't work for me. `edit_admin_content_path(article)` gives me `undefined method ` error and `admin_content_path(:action => edit, :id => some_article)` gives me `No route matches` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RESTful routes, why not use the Rails default routes?

So your `routes.rb` would look like

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :content
  resources :advanced
  resources :categories
  resources :comments
  ...
  <etc>
end
```

This does assume all your controllers are in the folder `admin` (but from your comment this seems to be the case.

If you do that, you can just use the standard route-helper: `edit_admin_content_path`.

If you want to do it manually, you should try adding a name to your route. E.g. as follows:

```
match "/admin/#{i}/:action(/:id)" => "admin/#{i}", :as => "admin_#{i}_with_action"
```

and then you should do something like

```
admin_content_with_action(:action => 'edit', :id => whatevvvva)
```

As a side-note: I really do not like the meta-programming in your `config/routes.rb`, if for whatever you really find that the default resources are not a right fit, I would advise to use methods instead (as explained [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0dd24728a088fcb4ae616bb5d62734aca5276b1b#commitcomment-1743800))

So for example in your `config/routes.rb` you would write:

```
def add_my_resource(resource_name)
  match "/#{resource_name}", :to => "#{resource_name}#index", :format => false
  match "/#{resource_name}(/:action(/:id))", :to => "#{resource_name}", :as => 'admin_#{resource_name}_with_action", :action => nil, :id => nil, :format => false
end

namespace :admin do
  add_my_resource :content
  add_my_resource :advanced
  add_my_resource :categories
  ...
end
```

which imho is *much* more readable.

But my advice, unless you really-really need to avoid it, would be to use the standard `resources` since you do not seem to add anything special.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I came across this problem when working with Typo (open source RoR blogware) for my assignment.